# Integrating kibana dashboards into an angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, kibana

I have my ElasticSearch setup with kibana showing different panels. I have another angularjs app. I would like to receive input in a  field, use angularjs and show kibana panels in my angularjs app itself.

Are there any tutorials/guides to achieve this?

I have googled quite a bit about this, but am unable to find any help.

You could also rephrase my question as "How do I embed a kibana dashboard in my AngularJS Single page website?"

Comment: Which version of Kibana are you using? 3 and 4 differs significantly

Comment: I'm very interested in an answer. I would like to integrate Kibana4 into an existing AngularJS App or at least use the same CSRF Token Auth for Kibana. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

In kibana4, the easiest way to embed a dashboard is using an iframe.  Click the "Share" button in the top-right corner to get the appropriate iframe tag.  Then edit it as needed to make it embed seamlessly.  Check out the [seamless](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) attribute.

Comment: Seamless attribute is not supported in modern browsers currently. Though iframe could be used i guess.

Answer (score 1):

When I google it your question, I have found some git article

May be it will help you to

You can use `iframe` read this 
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/729